# Flutter CupertinoButton child is not aligned properly

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I put a child into my `CupertinoButton`, it's aligned like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```dart
Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27, top: 27),
                        child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 60,
                              height: 60,
                              child: CupertinoButton(
                                color: Color(0xff383838),
                                onPressed: () {  },
                                child: Text("C", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Color(0xff78dbff)),)
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27, top: 27),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            child: CupertinoButton(
                              color: Color(0xff383838),
                              onPressed: () {  },
                              child: Text("±", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Color(0xff78dbff)),),
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27, top: 27),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            child: CupertinoButton(
                              color: Color(0xff383838),
                              onPressed: () {  },
                              child: Text("%", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Color(0xff78dbff)),),
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27, top: 27),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            child: CupertinoButton(
                              color: Color(0xff383838),
                              onPressed: () {  },
                              child: Text("÷", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27, color: Color(0xffff6e6e))),
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```

I can provide the full file if its needed.

I want the text to be aligned in the center of the button, not next to it. Changing `Text`'s `textAlign` to `TextAlign.center` does make it go slightly to the center, but still very far away. This problem doesn't occur in `TextButton`. This problem is not only with `Text`, after putting an icon as child, the problem is still the same. I tried using `Padding` to fix the problem but that did not help at all.

I'm using `CupertinoPageScaffold` as my scaffold. There are no modifications made to the parents of `Row`. I have no idea what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CupertinoButton has a default padding 16 for all sides. Hence, when you scaledown with SizedBox, the child still remain in its original position.

From cupertinobutton source code:

```
 const EdgeInsets _kButtonPadding = EdgeInsets.all(16.0);
```

Try the following by giving CupertinoButton a padding of zero:

```
Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27, top: 27),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  child: CupertinoButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    color: Color(0xff383838),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      "±",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Color(0xff78dbff)),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
```

Comment: @EmirSürmen Just an FYI, this works but seems like an issue with CupertinoButton. I tried this with MaterialButton, which looks the same btw, and it works as expected in a Row.

Comment: @temp_ thanks for the info, maybe I might open a bug report on the Flutter github repo